# Fast SSE threshold algorithm

Tags: performance, algorithm, optimization, sse, simd

I'm trying to come up with a very fast threshold algorithm using SSE to replace this:

```
uint8_t *pSrc, *pDst;

// Assume pSrc and pDst point to valid data

// Handle left edge
*pDst++ = *pSrc++;

// Likeness filter
for (uint32_t k = 2; k < width; k++, pSrc++, pDst++)
    if ((*pDst - *pSrc) * (*pDst - *pSrc) > 100 /*THRESHOLD_SQUARED*/) {
        *pDst = *pSrc;
    }
}

// Handle right edge
*pDst++ = *pSrc++;
```

So far I have this:

```
const uint8_t THRESHOLD = 10;

__attribute__((aligned (16))) static const uint8_t mask[16] = {
    THRESHOLD, THRESHOLD, THRESHOLD, THRESHOLD,
    THRESHOLD, THRESHOLD, THRESHOLD, THRESHOLD,
    THRESHOLD, THRESHOLD, THRESHOLD, THRESHOLD,
    THRESHOLD, THRESHOLD, THRESHOLD, THRESHOLD
};

__m128i xmm1, xmm3, xmm4, xmm5, xmm6, xmm7, xmm8, xmm9;
xmm1 = _mm_load_si128((__m128i const *)mask);
xmm6 = _mm_setzero_si128();

uint8_t *pSrc, *pDst;

// Assume pSrc and pDst point to valid data

// I have other code with another mask for the first 16 entries

for (uint32_t k = 16; k < (width - 16); k += 16, pSrc += 16, pDst += 16) {
    xmm3 = _mm_load_si128((__m128i const *)pDst);
    xmm4 = _mm_load_si128((__m128i const *)pSrc);
    xmm5 = _mm_unpacklo_epi8(xmm3, xmm6);
    xmm7 = _mm_unpackhi_epi8(xmm3, xmm6);
    xmm8 = _mm_unpacklo_epi8(xmm4, xmm6);
    xmm9 = _mm_unpackhi_epi8(xmm4, xmm6);
    xmm5 = _mm_sub_epi16(xmm5, xmm8);
    xmm7 = _mm_sub_epi16(xmm7, xmm9);
    xmm5 = _mm_abs_epi16(xmm5);
    xmm7 = _mm_abs_epi16(xmm7);
    xmm5 = _mm_packs_epi16(xmm5, xmm7);
    xmm5 = _mm_cmpgt_epi8(xmm5, xmm1);
    xmm3 = _mm_blendv_epi8(xmm3, xmm4, xmm5);
    _mm_store_si128((__m128i *)pDst, xmm3);
}

// I have other code with another mask for the last 16 entries
```

I have idea using another type of algorithm to handle the absolute value of the difference of two values (mainly to stay in U8 (uchar) space):

```
a' = a >> 1;
b' = b >> 1;
diff = (abs(sub(a' - b')) << 1) + ((a ^ b) & 1);
```

This would take 8 SSE instructions instead of the above 9 (not including any extra register moves the compiler generates) but I'm not sure if it is faster due to dependency latencies.

Does any other SSE expert have any better suggestions (using up to SSE 4.2)?

**Update 1 - Thanks to Yves's suggestion!**

```
const uint8_t THRESHOLD = 10;

__attribute__((aligned (16))) static const uint8_t mask[16] = {
    THRESHOLD, THRESHOLD, THRESHOLD, THRESHOLD,
    THRESHOLD, THRESHOLD, THRESHOLD, THRESHOLD,
    THRESHOLD, THRESHOLD, THRESHOLD, THRESHOLD,
    THRESHOLD, THRESHOLD, THRESHOLD, THRESHOLD
};

__m128i xmm1, xmm3, xmm4, xmm5, xmm6, xmm7;
xmm1 = _mm_load_si128((__m128i const *)mask);
xmm6 = _mm_setzero_si128();

uint8_t *pSrc, *pDst;

// Assume pSrc and pDst point to valid data

// I have other code with another mask for the first 16 entries

for (uint32_t k = 16; k < (width - 16); k += 16, pSrc += 16, pDst += 16) {
    xmm3 = _mm_load_si128((__m128i const *)pDst);
    xmm4 = _mm_load_si128((__m128i const *)pSrc);
    xmm5 = _mm_subs_epu8(xmm3, xmm4);
    xmm7 = _mm_subs_epu8(xmm4, xmm3);
    xmm5 = _mm_adds_epu8(xmm5, xmm7);
    xmm5 = _mm_subs_epu8(xmm5, xmm1);
    xmm5 = _mm_cmpeq_epi8(xmm5, xmm6);
    xmm4 = _mm_blendv_epi8(xmm4, xmm3, xmm5);
    _mm_store_si128((__m128i *)pDst, xmm4);
}

// I have other code with another mask for the last 16 entries
```

Comment: Why did you switch the tag from SSE to vectorization? SSE should be one of your tags.

Comment: The two code snippets do not do the same thing (the C code leaves the values that don't compare undefined whereas the SSE code sets them to zero). Also, you are almost certainly memory bandwidth bound with an operation as easy as SSE thresholding, so don't expect much of a difference between algorithms anyway.

Comment: @Damon, thanks to the blend instruction, the Dst values are preserved.

Comment: Let's assume both pSrc and pDst are in a high enough cache that memory bandwidth isn't a big issue.

Comment: BTW, I've checked the correctness of the SSE code (both old and new versus the C code).  They all produce the same values.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is an efficient alternative to compute the absolute difference, exploiting arithmetic saturation.

Indeed, saturated subtraction computes `A - B = Max(A - B, 0)`, so that `|A-B| = (A - B) + (B - A)`.

```
Diff= _mm_adds_epu8(_mm_subs_epu8(A, B), _mm_subs_epu8(B, A));
```

The sum will not saturate. This way, you stay with 16 x 8 bits unsigned and get a maximum throughput.

Comment: Thanks!  I was having a similar idea 10 minutes ago in the shower.  This seems to be exactly what I'm after.  I'll try it out.  I'll up vote as soon as my reputation gets to 15.

Comment: If I may: you needn't worry about register allocation anymore, the compiler will do the right thing for you, and you can use meaningful identifiers and complex expressions.

Comment: Works great with one additional change to the algorithm -_mm_min_epu8(Diff, 0x7f).  This is needed since _mm_cmpgt_epi8 uses signed values.  I'll post an updated version of the algorithm later today.  This method you have posted looks like it could have additional improvements for other algorithms - I can't wait to try them out!

Comment: For the unsigned comparison, alternatively to clamping under 0x7f, which reduces the range, you can use a saturated subtraction (_mm_subs_epu8 again) followed by a test for 0 (_mm_cmpeq_epi8 with a preloaded zero argument).

Comment: It also takes reversing the order of the operands for _mm_blendv_epi8 - b = _mm_blendv_epi8(b, a, mask) and moving b to the destination.

Comment: Do you confirm that _mm_maskmoveu_si128 is inefficient ? Would spare the load of Dst. (I guess you can also reverse the last subtraction to invert the blending mask.)

Comment: Agner Fog lists _mm_maskmoveu_si128 as a reciprocal throughput of 6.  This would explain the huge run time increase when I used this command.

Answer (score 1):

There are some useful functions from [Simd](http://sourceforge.net/projects/simd/) library:

```
inline __m128i Combine(__m128i mask, __m128i positive, __m128i negative)
{
    return _mm_or_si128(_mm_and_si128(mask, positive), _mm_andnot_si128(mask, negative));
}

inline __m128i AbsDifferenceU8(__m128i a, __m128i b)
{
    return _mm_sub_epi8(_mm_max_epu8(a, b), _mm_min_epu8(a, b));
}

inline __m128i LesserOrEqual8u(__m128i a, __m128i b)
{
    return _mm_cmpeq_epi8(_mm_min_epu8(a, b), a);
}
```

So SSE2 optimization will be look like this:

```
__m128i t = _mm_set1_epi8(threshold);
for (uint32_t k = 16; k < width - 16; pSrc += 16, pDst += 16)
{
    __m128i src = _mm_load_si128((__m128i*)pSrc);
    __m128i dst = _mm_load_si128((__m128i*)pDst);
    __m128i mask = LesserOrEqual8u(AbsDifferenceU8(src, dst), t);
    _mm_strore_si128((__m128i*)pDst, Combine(mask, dst, src);
}
```

Comment: That's an interesting alternative. I wonder if it has better ILP? The accepted answer uses three add/sub. So it's bound by the add throughput. Most Intel CPUs can do one SIMD add/clock cycle. Your solution uses one add and two min/max. Assuming the min/max can use another port then this would have higher throughput than only using add/sub.

Comment: _mm_cmpgt_epu8 is not a one single instruction command.  It requires an additional either _mm_min_epu8 or _mm_subs_epu8.  I've tried both the combine method and the blend instruction.  I'm not seeing much difference (as I stated above).